# how to check the current workspace of Eclipse and the project on that workspace using java program?

Tags: eclipse

how to check the current workspace of Eclipse and the project on that workspace using java program?

Comment: Could you give more details on what you want to do exactly? Are you in the context of an Eclipse plug-in or do you need a plain standalone java application to do that.

Comment: http://www.miuaiga.com/index.cfm/2009/9/3/Show-open-workspace-name-in-Eclipse-title-bar

Answer (score 3):

you can try this code to get the current workspace.

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
IPath location = root.getLocation();
```

Comment: I want a java program which will help me to get the name of current workspace and all the projects which are in current workspace..i want to use some conditional logic(if..else) on that.

Comment: getting error when i am using the above code: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.